# Using variable as part of a key in an array loop - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I've got an array that loops through and gathers the data, however I'm trying reuse that variable as a key in another array, when I echo out the variable it is a string however when I use it inside the variable it shows as null.

Take it as an example that the $value is equal to 'about'

**Order Layout Array Output**

```
Array
(
    [1] => benefits
    [2] => services
    [3] => about
    [4] => team
    [5] => successstories
    [6] => cta_banner
    [7] => social
    [8] => 
    [9] => 
    [10] => 
    [11] => 
)
```

**$bp_theme_options Array variables**

```
    $bp_theme_options['web_sec']['about']['show_row'] = "yes";
    $bp_theme_options['web_sec']['affiliates']['show_row'] = "yes";
    $bp_theme_options['web_sec']['benefits']['show_row'] = "yes";
    $bp_theme_options['web_sec']['blog']['show_row'] = "yes";
    $bp_theme_options['web_sec']['services']['show_row'] = "yes";
    $bp_theme_options['web_sec']['social']['show_row'] = "yes";
    $bp_theme_options['web_sec']['success_stories']['show_row'] = "yes";
    $bp_theme_options['web_sec']['team']['show_row'] = "yes";
    $bp_theme_options['web_sec']['cta_banner']['show_row'] = "yes";
```

**Incorrect output - $contents_show is NULL**

```
foreach ( $order_layout as $key => $value ) {
    if($value){
        var_dump($value) //returns 'about' string
        $contents_show = $bp_theme_options['web_sec'][$value]['show_row'];
        echo $contents_show;   //should return 'yes' returns NULL 
     }
 }
```

**Correct Output - $contents_show is 'yes';**

```
$contents_show = $bp_theme_options['web_sec']['about']['show_row'];
```

**$value returns**

```
string(8) "about"
```

Is this an issue with using a variable as a key inside another array? if I manually use 'about' it successfully grabs the variable.

Comment: What you see if you var_dump($bp_theme_options['web_sec'][$value]); ?

Comment: can't reproduce - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cfb774f3bb841964bbc780fe9da2f291e13e9509

Comment: can you add the array `$order_layout` and `$bp_theme_options`?

Comment: there must be other error cause your issue. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ac842500a93175f7a47d966fae69b22c58485344

Comment: We need to see `$order_layout` and `$bp_theme_options` to be able to help you with this problem. In general - there is no reason why you can't use any variable as an array key as long as the variable you are using eventually equates to a string.

Comment: @Sfili_81 that returns NULL, however when I manually add ['web_sec']['about'] it returns 'yes'.

Comment: Show the full output of the `var_dump($value)` statement.

Comment: Updated the question with more information - thanks!

Comment: Show the full output of the `var_dump($value)` statement!

Comment: @04FS Updated thanks

Comment: `string(8) "about"` - now, does “about” normally have _eight_ letters when you spell it? No? Well then you just found out that your $order_layout array does contain more than _just_ “about”, some invisible characters at the beginning or end maybe … and therefor this does not match the existing key `about` in the other array.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it work normally.

```
$order_layout = array(0=>'benefits',1=>'services',2=>'about',3=>'team',4=>'success_stories',5=>'cta_banner',6=>'social',7=>'',8=>'',9=>'',10=>'');
$bp_theme_options['web_sec']['about']['show_row'] = "yes";
$bp_theme_options['web_sec']['affiliates']['show_row'] = "yes";
$bp_theme_options['web_sec']['benefits']['show_row'] = "yes";
$bp_theme_options['web_sec']['blog']['show_row'] = "yes";
$bp_theme_options['web_sec']['services']['show_row'] = "yes";
$bp_theme_options['web_sec']['social']['show_row'] = "yes";
$bp_theme_options['web_sec']['success_stories']['show_row'] = "yes";
$bp_theme_options['web_sec']['team']['show_row'] = "yes";
$bp_theme_options['web_sec']['cta_banner']['show_row'] = "yes";
foreach ( $order_layout as $key => $value ) {
    if ($value) {
        $contents_show = $bp_theme_options['web_sec'][$value]['show_row'];
        var_dump($contents_show . "<br>");   //should return 'yes' and returns 'yes'
    }
}
```

Output:

```
string 'yes<br>' (length=7)
string 'yes<br>' (length=7)
string 'yes<br>' (length=7)
string 'yes<br>' (length=7)
string 'yes<br>' (length=7)
string 'yes<br>' (length=7)
string 'yes<br>' (length=7)
```

You have a different names in $order_layout and $bp_theme_options (check successstories and success_stories). Maybe you have a extra space in 'about' name in $order_layout?

Answer (score 1):

In My Case Work Perfectly.

```
<?php
$bp_theme_options['web_sec']['about']['show_row'] = "yes";
$bp_theme_options['web_sec']['affiliates']['show_row'] = "yes";
$bp_theme_options['web_sec']['benefits']['show_row'] = "yes";
$bp_theme_options['web_sec']['blog']['show_row'] = "yes";
$bp_theme_options['web_sec']['services']['show_row'] = "yes";
$bp_theme_options['web_sec']['social']['show_row'] = "yes";
$bp_theme_options['web_sec']['success_stories']['show_row'] = "yes";
$bp_theme_options['web_sec']['team']['show_row'] = "yes";
$bp_theme_options['web_sec']['cta_banner']['show_row'] = "yes";

$order_layout = [ 1 =>'benefits', 2  =>'services', 3 =>'about', 4 =>'team', 5 =>'success_stories', 6 =>'cta_banner', 7 =>'social'];

foreach ( $order_layout as $key => $value ) {
    if($value){
        if(isset($bp_theme_options['web_sec'][$value]['show_row'])){
            $contents_show = $bp_theme_options['web_sec'][$value]['show_row'];
            if(isset($contents_show)){
               var_dump($contents_show.'--'.$value);
            }
        }
     }
}
?>
```

Output:

```
string(13) "yes--benefits" 
string(13) "yes--services" 
string(10) "yes--about" 
string(9) "yes--team" 
string(20) "yes--success_stories" 
string(15) "yes--cta_banner" 
string(11) "yes--social"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you store the reference of the value of the actual loop ?

```
foreach ( $order_layout as $key => $value ) {
    if($value){
        var_dump($value) //returns 'about' string
        $value_ref = &$value;
        $contents_show = $bp_theme_options['web_sec'][$value_ref]['show_row'];
        echo $contents_show;   //should return 'yes' returns NULL 
     }
 }
```